# How to find the most repeated field of a column in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and i have a question ! What if I want to find the most repeated field in column B which is not similar to column A ?

```
Column A       Column B
 Sam             Sam
 Alex            David
 David           David
 Sarah           Alice
 Alice           Sam
 Sam             Alice
 Anna            Sam
```

I would like to exclude if names in column A and column B are same and then find the most repeated names in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) first and then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with selecting `index` values by `[]`:

```
print (df)
  Column A Column B
0      Sam      Sam
1     Alex    David
2     Alex     Mary
3    David    David
4    Sarah    Alice
5    Alice      Sam
6      Sam    Alice
7      Sam      Joe
8      Sam      Joe
9     Anna      Sam

print (df.loc[~df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A']), 'Column B'])
2    Mary
7     Joe
8     Joe
Name: Column B, dtype: object


df = df.loc[~df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A']), 'Column B'].value_counts().index[0]
print (df)
Joe
```

Comment: if i would like to group them by "id", can i try df.groupby ?

Comment: I am not sure if understand, because no `id`, but if need groupby by column `id` need `df = df.groupby('id') ..add some function like size, sum, `

Comment: i was wondering in case column A and column B have "id", then it could be better to find this condition, after grouped by id

Comment: I think no, `id` i not necessary.

Comment: hello..can i add one more condition in this ? If column B should not be equal to column A and column C ?? I tried with isin, but i can add only one datatype

Comment: Do you think `(df.loc[~(df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A']) &  df['Column B'].isin(df['Column C'])), 'Column B'])` ?

Comment: thanks ! and i used .value_counts().index[:3] to get top 3 names :) thanks to you !

Comment: Hello Jezrael !! ^^ I have data that is 4gb big ! And i get memory error when i run this code ! is there any alternative command to do this ?

Comment: I think not, unfortunately :( Maybe try `np.in1d(df['Column B'], (df['Column A'])` but not sure if better.

Comment: Sorry, now I have no idea (and have to go away from PC). Maybe try post new question with this specific problem. :(